# How to delete previous arrows already plot

Tags: pine-script

I try to make a script which will display an Up Arrow for the more recent lowest candle.
So far my script displays an arrow as soon as a new low is found.
This gives the following result.
https://www.tradingview.com/x/eRbdaj3r/

But I would like to only display the last arrow. So, I just want to highlight the most recent low.
My problem is that I do not manage to find a when to delete/remove previous arrows once a new low is found.

I spent hours to look for a solution to this problem but cannot find it. Neither a solution nor a workaround.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my script so far

```
strategy(title="W Detector", overlay=true, max_bars_back=3000, initial_capital=1000, commission_value=0.1)

newLowIndex = 0
previousLowIndex = 0

newHighIndex = 0
PreviousHighIndex = 0

float newLowPrice = 0.0
float previousLowPrice = 0.0

float newHighPrice = 0.0
float previousHighPrice = 0.0

newLowDetected = 0

nTemp = 0

//Reload values from previous run
//INDEXES
newLowIndex := na(newLowIndex[1]) ? 0 : newLowIndex[1]
previousLowIndex := na(previousLowIndex[1]) ? 0 : previousLowIndex[1]
newHighIndex := na(newHighIndex[1]) ? 0 : newHighIndex[1]
PreviousHighIndex := na(PreviousHighIndex[1]) ? 0 : PreviousHighIndex[1]

//PRICES
newLowPrice := na(newLowPrice[1]) ? close : newLowPrice[1]
previousLowPrice := na(previousLowPrice[1]) ? close : previousLowPrice[1]
newHighPrice := na(newHighPrice[1]) ? close : newHighPrice[1]
previousHighPrice := na(previousHighPrice[1]) ? close : previousHighPrice[1]

//Increment this index for each iteration
newLowIndex := newLowIndex + 1
previousLowIndex := previousLowIndex + 1
newHighIndex := newHighIndex + 1
PreviousHighIndex := PreviousHighIndex + 1

//reset vars for this run
newLowDetected := 0


if previousLowPrice == 0 or close < previousLowPrice
    newLowDetected := 1
    previousLowPrice := close
    //reset the index for the new low
    previousLowIndex := newLowIndex //save this value as the previouw low before reseting
    newLowIndex := 0
    
    
//Draw an arrow on for the new law and delete the previous one.

plotshape(newLowDetected, style=shape.arrowup, location=location.belowbar)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pine does not allow changes to already drawn charts on historical bars.
For an idea of a workaround, try using the features of the `line` drawing functions. They can be created and deleted on historical bars.Perhaps it will not be so beautiful, but the needed bars will be marked on the chart.